# Getting pixel color at point takes too long for HEIC images

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

The method below gets the pixel color at a specific point in the selected photo. When a JPG is selected, the image process below is fast. 
When a HEIC photo is selected, the image process below is slow. Can be approx 40x slower (7 secs vs 5 mins).

I was wondering why that is and what I can do to fix it? Just to be clear the code below works, just takes a long time for HEIC to be processed.

```
class func getPixelColorAtPoint(point:CGPoint, sourceView: UIView) -> UIColor{

        let pixel = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.allocate(capacity: 4)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
        let context = CGContext(data: pixel, width: 1, height: 1, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)
        var color: UIColor? = nil

        if let context = context {
            context.translateBy(x: -point.x, y: -point.y)
            sourceView.layer.render(in: context)

            color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(pixel[0])/255.0,
                            green: CGFloat(pixel[1])/255.0,
                            blue: CGFloat(pixel[2])/255.0,
                            alpha: CGFloat(pixel[3])/255.0)

            pixel.deallocate(capacity: 4)
        }
        return color!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it’s taking 5 minutes, I assume you must be calling this routine repeatedly, rendering this `sourceView` each time. You should render the whole view to a complete pixel buffer once and only once, and then you can efficiently retrieve the color of multiple pixels from this buffer.

For example:

```
var data: Data?
var width: Int!
var height: Int!

func pixelColor(at point: CGPoint, for sourceView: UIView) -> UIColor? {
    if data == nil { fillBuffer(for: sourceView) }

    return data?.withUnsafeBytes { rawBufferPointer in
        let pixels = rawBufferPointer.bindMemory(to: Pixel.self)
        let pixel = pixels[Int(point.y) * width + Int(point.x)]
        return pixel.color
    }
}

func fillBuffer(for sourceView: UIView) {
    // get image snapshot

    let bounds = sourceView.bounds
    let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
    format.scale = 1
    let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds, format: format).image { _ in
        sourceView.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    }
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return }

    // prepare to get pixel buffer

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
    width = Int(bounds.width)
    height = Int(bounds.height)

    // populate and save pixel buffer

    if let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4 * width, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) {
        context.draw(cgImage, in: bounds)
        data = context.data.flatMap { Data(bytes: $0, count: 4 * width * height) }
    }
}
```

Clearly, render this to the buffer however you want, but the basic idea is to save the pixel buffer to some `Data` from which you can quickly retrieve color values.

By the way, rather than navigating the RGBA bytes separately, I think it’s useful to use a `struct`, like below, to render slightly more intuitive code:

```
struct Pixel {
    let red: UInt8
    let green: UInt8
    let blue: UInt8
    let alpha: UInt8
}

extension Pixel {
    var color: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(red) / 255,
                       green: CGFloat(green) / 255,
                       blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255,
                       alpha: CGFloat(alpha) / 255)
    }
}
```

The more interesting question, IMHO, is why you are retrieving the color of multiple pixels. Do you really need the color for individual pixels, or are you doing some calculation based upon the results (e.g. histograms, average color, etc.)? I.e. if you really only need colors pixel-by-pixel, that’s fine, but if there’s a broader problem you’re trying to solve, we might be able to show you more efficient approaches than processing pixel by pixel. These range from parallelized routines, vImage high performance image processing, etc. But we can’t say more without knowing what you’re doing with these repeated calls to retrieve the pixel colors.